# JPA OneToMany with composite keys in parent and children

Tags: jpa

I have two tables that represent authorizations for users to manage certain applications on given offices. One table has a composite pk of office and user and holds information about those, the other has a composite key of office, user and applicationId (table 2 holds no other information)

```
+---------------+           +---------------+  
|    Table1     |           |    Table2     |
+---------------+           +---------------+  
| - userId      | 1       n | - userId      | 
| - officeId    | <-------> | - officeId    | 
| <other data>  |           | - applicId    |    
+---------------+           +---------------+
```

How do I represent this in JPA? At the moment I have this:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class Table1_pk implements Serializable {  
    private BigDecimal officeId;
    private String userId;
}


@Data
@Embeddable
public class Table2_pk implements Serializable {
    @Embedded
    private Table1_pk table1pk;

    private int applicId;
}
```

and the entities:
    @Entity
    public class Table1 implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId
        private Table1_pk table1Id;
    }

```
@Entity
public class Table2 implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Table2_pk table2Id;
}
```

Is this right so far? How can I represent the oneToMany relation the two table have?

The key field names are the same on both tables (so userId is called "userId" on both table1 and table2 in the DB, table2 really just has a field more with the application code)

Comment: I found this, going through it at the moment, it might be what I was looking for: http://www.kawoolutions.com/Technology/JPA,_Hibernate,_and_Co./JPA_Composite_Key_Variants